# How would i loop through the graphicItems each item in Visio using vba?

Tags: vba, visio

I have a graphics as per the below snap, where i want to make Bold to the 1st item and last item should be italic. So to achieve this i think i have to loop though the each item of the certain graphics in Visio.

[image]

So i have tried the the below VBA code, but it only displays the graphics item ID and name.

```
For intCounter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Masters.Count 
    If ActiveDocument.Masters(intCounter).Type = visTypeDataGraphic Then 
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Masters(intCounter).Name, ActiveDocument.Masters(intCounter).ID 
    End If 
Next
```

So I need the detail process to loop through the graphics item for each element so that my findings can be handled ?

[image]

I have several data graphics entities in a page and I want data graphic item should be changed all such entities at once. I don't find any option in "Edit Data Graphic" to change its item wise properties like 'Bold', 'Italic' etc.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details for your purposes! You need change GraphicItem into Document stencil or each entity in Pages?

Comment: i have several data graphics entities in a page and i want data graphic item should be changed all such entities at once. I don't find any option in "Edit Data Graphic" to change its item wise properties like 'Bold', 'Italic' etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you link External data with your document Visio engine automatically add few hidden build-in master shapes to Document stencil.
[image]

You can find these changes via **Drawing Explorer window**.

Each master shape contain some sub-shapes into.

[image]

You must iterate these sub-shapes!!!